# Low Speed Connection for VS Code servers to download extensions

Tags: python, django

Two days ago, I installed Ubuntu and deleted windows, then I installed VS Code from Snap Store, now I have a problem with VS Code servers to download extensions. I'm from Iran and we have a low-speed connection, because of it, I get errors for a low connection. Is there a way to install extensions for VS Code? any help will be grateful.

I get the XHR timeout: undefinedms

How can I install VS Code extensions due to low connection speed?

Comment: have you selected a specific server for your ubuntu. if not, then select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download extensions as a `.vsix` file.

Go [VS marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) and download your extensions on your ubuntu server (or other devices, and copy to your ubuntu using disks like usb).

And VScode extension tab -> meatball menu(...) -> Click 'Install from VSIX' tab and select vsix path.

Also you can install directly using Ctrl + Shift + P(Command palette), type 'Install from VSIX' and select vsix path.